# Moving part of algorithm horizontally preserving indentation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

Let us consider the following MWE codes

**Code 1**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm2e}[H]

    \underline{Algorithm}\\
    \vspace{2mm}
     \underline{Step 1} : Step \\ 
    \For{$i = 1\cdots n$}{
    2 + 3 \;
    }
\caption{Example}

\end{algorithm2e}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above code is not aligned but intended properly

**Code 2:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm2e}[H]

    \underline{Algorithm}\\
    \vspace{2mm}
     \underline{Step 1} : Step \\
   \hspace{1.25cm}   \For{$i = 1\cdots n$}{
    \hspace{1.25cm} 2 + 3 \;
    \hspace{1.25cm} }
  \caption{Example}

  \end{algorithm2e}  
 \end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue in this code is that the end is not properly intended with for, end did not obey *hspace*.

**I want to shift the for loop of algorithm to right without causing indentation issues**, if I use *hspace*, then end is not aligning properly with for.

How to achieve this proper alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution relies on `algorithm2e` internals, so it might break if the implementation of `algorithm2e` changes.

You can create a new algorithm block using `\algocf@push` and `\algocf@pop`.
To hide the complexity, this can be hidden in an environemnt: After

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{algoindent}{m}{%
  \algocf@push{#1}\hbox\bgroup\vtop\bgroup
  \algocf@addskiptotal
}{%
  \egroup\egroup
  \algocf@pop{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

you can create in indented block with `\begin{algoindent}{2cm} ... \end{algoindent}`. Of course this requires knowing the width of the label but this can be automated too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{algoindent}{m}{%
  \algocf@push{#1}\hbox\bgroup\vtop\bgroup
  \algocf@addskiptotal
}{%
  \egroup\egroup
  \algocf@pop{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentEnvironment{algolabel}{m o}{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\underline{#1} : }
  \dimen0=\wd0
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode\box0 \IfValueT{#2}{#2\\}%
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\algoindent\expandafter{\the\dimen0}
}{\endalgoindent}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm2e}[H]

    \underline{Algorithm}\\
    \vspace{2mm}
    \begin{algolabel}{Step 1}[Step]
    \For{$i = 1\cdots n$}{
    2 + 3 \;
    }
    \end{algolabel}
\caption{Example}

\end{algorithm2e}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind user can you write to hanugm to know to which person I can give the bonus of +50 points? Thanks.

Comment: Please give a bonus to this user...

Comment: @hanugm done! And I have offered +1 to the other user +1.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\IncMargin{5em}
\begin{algorithm2e}
    \underline{Algorithm}\\
    \vspace{2mm}
     \underline{Step 1} : Step \\
    \For{$i = 1\cdots n$}{
    2 + 3 \;
    }
\caption{Example}
\end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

As stated on page 5 of the manual. More explanation on page 30 of the manual.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity in my question, I want only for loop to move horizontally.  I mean for loop has to come exactly under *Step* like code 2 in my example

Comment: @hanugm I have put a bounty for you because your question has not received enough attention. Do you like the Denis' answer? Thus I give to denis +50.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you. No, don't give...

Comment: @hanugm Are there any news?

Comment: No, no one answered till now either here or in my surroundings,  don't know whether it is such complex...